# Adding System Calls in Linux 0.01 for a "Semaphore" using C++

Tags: c++, linux, semaphore, system-calls

I'm trying to figure how to to implement a set of system calls that provide a semaphore (without busy-waiting) module in Linux 0.01. I want these system calls to allow a process to request for a fresh semaphore and use it for process synchronization.

I want to write these in C++ but I'm having trouble getting them to work. Anyone have simple solution?

- (system call #110) int sema_request(int value): this function returns a fresh semaphore if succeeds and -1 otherwise. The fresh semaphore is initialized to "value". You implementation should support at least 10 different semaphores in the entire OS.
- (system call #111) int sema_wait(int s): this function implements the "wait" operation on semaphore s. It returns 0 if succeeds and -1 otherwise.
- (system call #112) int sema_signal(int s): this function performs the "signal" operation on semaphore s. It return 0 if succeeds and -1 otherwise.

Comment: it's possible to write something in c++ for the new kernels, but why on earth would you do this for 0.01?

Comment: 1) why do you want to add this to a prehistoric kernel?  2) http://kerneltrap.org/node/2067 for Linus' view on C++ in the kernel  and 3) what about sysv ipc semaphores?  They've been there forever and are reliable.

Comment: @Griwes Let's talk about this once ReaverOS has risen to the status of successful, usable, general purpose, accepted OS. :-)

Comment: @fvu: it's learning project, despite of the description. And his business (or, PR) success does not mean he is not idiot.

Comment: "Anyone have simple solution?" for some obscure, one-off task in some piece of code no-one used for decades? I commend your unorthodox sense of humour.
(just in case that wasn't a joke, the answer is: "not very likely")

Answer (score 0):

You won't be learning much if someone else is doing your work for you, but here's a user-mode Semaphore implementation that I wrote:

https://github.com/vinniefalco/VFLib/blob/master/modules/vf_core/threads/vf_Semaphore.h
https://github.com/vinniefalco/VFLib/blob/master/modules/vf_core/threads/vf_Semaphore.cpp

You will of course need to map WaitableEvent, SpinLock, and Atomic  to their appropriate counterparts based on your environment (condition variable, mutex, and atomic integer operation respectively). You'll also need to provide a simple stack, or you can adapt the lock-free implementation from my library. Note that if you do decide to go lock-free, you'll have to keep the "deleted list" hanging around or you'll get the ABA problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your API design looks okay and it should works with well implementation.

You could initialize 10 kernel level semaphores on driver loading. 
When sema_request calls, return index 0~9 if request valid. 
When sema_wait(index) call, call the corresponding semaphore''s wait and vice versa.

The kernel level semphore has implemented all features you needed (blocking, waiting Queues, wake up) and main purpose of your driver code is write a good driver interfaces and print out something message if any problem

Reference:
https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/rusty/kernel-locking/c93.html